# TypeError: _Contexts_Authcontext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.useAuth() is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am trying Context API but it throws an error saying useAuth is undefined. I have tried many things but none of them worked. I have been stuck for a few hours now.
Below is the code.

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const setAuth = (authBool) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(authBool)
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, setAuth }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

App.js

```
import {render} from "react-dom"    
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuth, AuthProvider } from './Contexts/Authcontext';


const cookies = new Cookies();

export default function App() {
  const { setAuth } = useAuth()
    useEffect(() => {
      getSession();
    }, []);
  
    const getSession = () => {
      fetch("/authorizer/session/", {
        credentials: "same-origin",
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
          setAuth(data.isAuthenticated);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    };

    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <AuthProvider>
                <div id="App">
                    My APP
                </div>
            </AuthProvider>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("main")
render(<App/>, appDiv)
```

I checked for spelling mistakes, I checked whether I exported the context and both are fine.

**EDIT:**
I found the error is occuring at the following line in the JS. It through error useAuth undefined at the below line. Do not know the reason as import is done correctly.

```
function App() {
  const {
    setAuth
  } = (0,_Contexts_Authcontext__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.useAuth)();
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sad, not a single answer :) nor any comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're seeing is due to the order of operations in your component tree.

You're trying to use the `useAuth` hook in the `App` component, but the `App` component itself is responsible for wrapping its children in the `AuthProvider`. The `useAuth` hook, which relies on the `AuthContext`'s context value, cannot be used in the `App` component since `App` itself hasn't been wrapped by the `AuthProvider`.

To fix this, you need to restructure your components such that the `App` component (or any component where you're trying to use the `useAuth` hook) is a child of a component wrapped by the `AuthProvider`.

Here's one way you can fix this:

1. Create a new main component that wraps the `App` component with the `AuthProvider`:

```
// Root.js
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import { AuthProvider } from './Contexts/Authcontext';

function Root() {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <AuthProvider>
        <App />
      </AuthProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

2. Now, in your main render code, render the `Root` component:

```
// main code
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Root from './Root';

const appDiv = document.getElementById("main");
render(<Root />, appDiv);
```

3. Leave your `App` component unchanged. Now, since `App` is a child of `Root` which is wrapped by `AuthProvider`, you should be able to use the `useAuth` hook inside the `App` component without any issues.

This restructuring ensures that any component where you use the `useAuth` hook is actually within the context of `AuthProvider`.

Comment: Thanks Umar, it is working like charm